# Memory leak shown in MAT as GC root: Native Stack

Tags: java, memory-leaks, java-native-interface, out-of-memory

I have some third library code that I run and after some time I run into `OutOfMemoryError`. So I fired up the Eclipse MAT and analyzed the memory. Now it seems the memory can't be disposed because there is an object that is a shown as `GC root: Native Stack`. Reading the [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.mat.ui.help%2Fconcepts%2Fgcroots.html):

> In or out parameters in native code, such as user defined JNI code or JVM internal code. This is often the case as many methods have native parts and the objects handled as method parameters become GC roots. For example, parameters used for file/network I/O methods or reflection.

Now my question is: How can I confirm that the object is used in JNI or elsewhere (i.e. how do I find the code where it is used)? Can I somehow dispose the object? What other options do I have?

Thanks for the help already!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Objects being shown as `GC root: Native Stack` turned out to be a problem of the Eclipse Debugger. When the application was started without the debugger (i.e. with 'run' instead of 'debug') the problem disappeared. This was also the reason that I couldn't find the code where the objects where used in JNI inside my project (cause they weren't).

Finding the *real* memory leak without debugging was a bit hard, but using Eclipse MAT and its 'find Leak suspects' feature helped *a lot*!

Comment: Do you know why the eclipse debugger holds on to classes and prevents them from getting unloaded?

Comment: The same problem appears when using IntelliJ Debugger.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not have an access to the source code you can try and decompile it with any available decompilation tools (provided the code is not obfuscated). And then you can analyze the source code.